# How to update a row from external data in datatable?

Tags: jquery, grid, datatables-1.10

I try to update some fields in a row, the problem is that it does not work.

```
  borrar = table.row($(this).parents('tr'));
  var datos = {
    id : $("#id").val(),
    tipo : $("#tipo").val(),
    rol : $("#rol").val(),
    descripcion : $("#descripcion").val(),
    estado : $('#estado').prop('checked')};
  borrar.data()[1] = datos.rol;
  borrar.data()[2] = datos.descripcion;
  console.log(borrar.data()); //(5) ["2", "aaaa", "aaa", "Activo".....
  borrar.invalidate().draw();
  console.log(borrar.data()); //Here return default value (5) ["2", "Fábrica", "Usuario Fábrica del Sistema", "Activo"....
```

Use DataTables 1.10.12

Comment: There is a few pecularities in the above. Is the table based on DOM or a JSON source?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved with:

```
borrar.invalidate('data').draw();
```

When the table is based on DOM